# Facebook SDK login statuses

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Based on the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#example), calling `getLoginStatus()` returns one of three responses for status: `connected`, `not_authorized`, `unknown`.

What baffles me is the status `connected` where it says:

> The person is logged into Facebook, and has logged into your webpage.

Now the question I have here is how does the Facebook SDK know whether user has logged into my webpage?

Concretely, I have a Laravel/Vue app which on `login()` calls FB SDK `login()` method, and after that fetches (FB) logged in user data which I then check against my database and based on response either register them or log them in. That response is never returned to FB, so I have no idea what does it actually mean then from SDK perspective that user has logged into my webpage?

Comment: Better phrasing would perhaps be, they used your app to login, and now have an active user session, with a token that you can use to make API requests. The JS SDK will recognize them as “logged in” to your site, when they are _on_ your site, based on the cookies and cross-domain communication in the background. What your website actually _does_ with the available information, is up to you, that is not really Facebook’s business any more, and is not reflected in this login status.

Comment: So `connected` in that context means that my website was the FB request originator, and got back a positive response?

Comment: It basically means that the user logged in to your app, and you currently got a valid user access token. Not much more than that.

Comment: But what does "log in to my app" means? From my perspective he is logged in when I check his credentials against DB and store him as being auth user in session. The fact that I am using FB for authorization has nothing to do with auth status of my app, as I could as well authenticate user without FB

Comment: It means they used your app to authenticate, not much more. Whatever you do with that information next, is up to you. If you check anything against your own DB, and write stuff into your own user session - that does not have anything to do with Facebook any more.

Comment: A merely client-side app, that doesn’t do any of that, can use this status to determine if it has a Facebook user who authenticated themselves, and for whom the app now has a valid user access token, that can be used to make API requests. Don’t assign any more meaning to it.